# How to display `top` results sorted by memory usage by a process in KB/MB?

Tags: linux, command-line, process, memory, top

I have known about `top` command. When I using this command, I got only the memory usage of a process in terms of PERCENTAGE(%MEM) only. Is there any option to get the memory details in terms of Bytes(KB/MB).
Its useful if i get my requirement through other command also.